# Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler

Tags: java, gwt, ant, gwt2

I am trying to compile and build my GWT 2.6 Project and when I run my Ant script it immediately throws the message `Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler` in the Eclipse console.

Following is the piece from my Ant Script where the compilation sticks and reports an error.

```
<target name="gwtc" description="GWT compile to JavaScript (production mode)">
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
```

My gwt-dev.jar is not corrupted, I verified this by changing the classname to com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode, Just to make sure the Ant script properly picks the jar or not and it does work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your java task has no classpath or classpath reference specified.

Comment: Sorry I missed it. It's there in my ant script. That's how the script works when the classname ="com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode"..